# why [Required] attribution doesn't cause cause errors in modelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC, just a question on model validation. Below is my code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ViewResult Index([Required]string nonExistName)
        {            
           // put a debugger here
           return View();
        }
}
```

so when I ran the app, the default route was used, clearly there won't be anything called `nonExistName` in query string or route values, so the model binding should raise an error in `ModelState`.

But there was actually  no validation error at all, I set a breakpoint to check the state of `ModelState`, no errors at all. I also tried `ModelState.IsValid`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Index([Required]string nonExistName)
   {            
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         return View();
      }
      return NotFound();
   }
}
```

still have the normal Index view returned.

Why `[Required]` doesn't cause an error in `ModelState`? if I put the `[Required]` i above the model class's property, then it will work. but why it doesn't work  when placed in the action method?

Comment: Did you try checking if model is valid with ModelState.IsValid?

Comment: @Matt   Yes, I tried `ModelState.IsValid`, still doesn't work, please see my edited post

Comment: Is `nonExistName` equal to "" or null?

Comment: @Matt `nonExistName` is `null`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do NULL check?

Comment: @Matt   yes, that would be easier, but I want to know why `[Required]` doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you describing is called *Top-level Node Validation*. You can read more about it in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#top-level-node-validation

An important note is that it works a bit differently depending on what version of ASP.NET Core you are running. Make sure you have the feature enable, as described in the docs:

> When running with CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1 or later, top-level
>   node validation is enabled by default. Otherwise, top-level node
>   validation is disabled. The default option can be overridden by
>   setting the AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes property in
>   (Startup.ConfigureServices), as shown here:

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
    {
        options.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes = true;
    })
```